# What is the public description of the "attempted Jedi coup"?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, revenge-of-the-sith

I know that Palpatine used fixed recordings, first to portray the Jedi as staging an unprovoked coup, second to cover up his Sith identity, so that the Jedi can persuasively look like they are trying to seize power for themselves from helpless Force Muggles.

One point of contention I have is how Palpatine explained his survival, even in spite of the fact that he was "left scarred and deformed". The Senate should know better than most how formidable the Jedi are, especially if they have intent to kill, as the suggestion that they are taking over by force of arms, and going as far as to attack the head of state, would necessarily imply.

Is there any detailed account of the public version of the "Jedi coup"?